# Ruby Not Installing

Tags: ruby

I'm following this blog to install Ruby on my Ubuntu 13.10 system. I'm good right up until I try to do "ruby-install ruby 2.2.0" and then I get the following error messages:

```
brandonglajchen@glajchen-laptop:~/ruby-install-0.5.0$ ruby-install ruby 2.2.0
>>> Installing ruby 2.2.0 into /home/brandonglajchen/.rubies/ruby-2.2.0 ...
>>> Installing dependencies for ruby 2.2.0 ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package zlib1g-dev
E: Unable to locate package libyaml-dev
E: Unable to locate package libssl-dev
E: Unable to locate package libgdbm-dev
E: Unable to locate package libreadline-dev
E: Unable to locate package libncurses5-dev
E: Unable to locate package libffi-dev
!!! Installing dependencies failed!
```

apt-get update gives me this:

```
W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 082CCEDF94558F59
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: I added the apt-get update results into the main post.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

13.10 isn't a supported release any longer. You'll need to change your apt sources to point to an old-releases server

```
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/
```

and so on

Comment: This completely solved it, thank you.